# How to "refresh" a variable from file

Tags: python, import

I would like a variable to be stored in `.py` file and be imported into a main Python program.

Let me explain the problem in code. In my home folder I have the following files:

- testcode.py
- testmodule.py

`testcode` contains the following code:

```
import pprint

while __name__ == '__main__':
    import testmodule
    variableFromFile=testmodule.var
    print("Variable from file is "+str(variableFromFile))
    print("Enter variable:")
    variable=input()
    Plik=open('testowymodul.py','w')
    Plik.write('var='+variable)
    Plik.close()
```

and `testmodule` contains:

```
var=0
```

Now when I launched `testcode.py`, and input as variables `1,2,3,4,5` I got the following output:

```
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
1
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
2
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
3
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
4
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
5
Variable from file is 0
Enter variable:
```

But I would like to refresh this variable every time it is printed on screen, so I expect in this line:

```
print("Variable from file is "+str(variableFromFile))
```

to update the variable's value. Instead, I get in output only the first value of the variable, so the program print 0 every time. Only restarting the program will refresh the value of `var`.

Is there a way to import variables from file, change them at runtime and then then use their updated values later on in the script?

Comment: After you update that variable, you want to persist it someplace (not in your python source code). The easiest thing would be a little text file, but there are also light weight databases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your basic problem stems from the use of the variable in the testmodule.py file. As written you code imports this file and thus the pyhton interpreter assigns the value of testmodule.var to the contents thyat exist at load time. The code which attempts to update the variable isn't working the way you intended, since Plik.write('var='+variable) is creating a text string of the form "var = n". Thus subsequent attempts to import the testmodule and get the testmodule.var variable will result in a 0 value.

To fix this problem, as suggested by @JONSG, requires you abandon the import context and do something along the lines of the following:

```
#Contents of testmodule.txt file
0  

#Contents of the testcode.py file
def readVar(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().strip()
    
def writeVar(fn, val):
    with open(fn,'w') as f:
        f.write(val)

def runcode():        
    varfile = 'testmodule.txt'  #Assumes testmodule.txt is in same folder as code
    variableFromFile= readVar(varfile)
    print("Variable from file is "+str(variableFromFile))
    variable=input("Enter variable: ")
    writeVar(varfile, variable)


def main():
    runcode()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now every time you run the file, the latest variable data will be loaded and then updated with a new value.